# C++ Integer overflow problem when casting from double to unsigned int

Tags: c++, datetime, time, casting, type-conversion

I need to convert time from one format to another in C++ and it must be cross-platform compatible. I have created a structure as my time container. The structure fields must also be `unsigned int` as specified by legacy code.

```
struct time{   
unsigned int timeInteger;   
unsigned int timeFraction;
} time1, time2;
```

Mathematically the conversion is as follows:

time2.timeInteger = time1.timeInteger  + 2208988800

time2.timeFraction = (time1.timeFraction * 20e-6) * 2e32

Here is my original code in C++ however when I attempt to write to a binary file, the converted time does not match with the truth data. I think this problem is due to a type casting mistake? This code will compile in VS2008 and will execute.

```
void convertTime(){
   time2.timeInteger  = unsigned int(time1.timeInteger + 2209032000);
   time2.timeFraction = unsigned int(double(time1.timeFraction) * double(20e-6)*double(pow(double(2),32)));
}
```

Comment: @shuttle87: "better" is open to interpretation, but in this case translates to "won't compile", which few people find an improvement in itself.

Comment: @shuttle87: `reinterpret_cast` won't work for converting numeric types; you need `static_cast` for that. And this isn't using C-style casting, it's using C++ initialisation-style conversion. Personally, I find that easier on the eye than `static_cast` for numeric conversions.

Comment: Although I believe `unsigned int(value)` is invalid for technical reasons, but accepted by most compilers.

Comment: @Mike I am using VS2008 and the code will compile and execute

Comment: Are you sure you want 2e32 and not pow(2,32)? Either way your formula seems a little suspect.

Comment: @Mike, the math formula or the c++ implementation?

Comment: What the hell does convertTime actually accomplish?

Comment: @DeadMG: I have two time formats that have different epochs and different accuracies... convertTime just converts one time format to another

Comment: @Elpez: Oh, ok. Then yes, they should be different types.

Comment: @DeadMG: What do you mean by different types? I plan to create different structures, but the integer overflow problem with the fraction is not addressed.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say static_cast<double> here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, but are you assuming that `2e32` == `2^32`? This assumption would make sense if you're trying to scale the result into a 32 bit integer. In fact `2e32` == `2 * 10^32`

Answer (score 1):

Slightly unrelated, I think you should rethink your type design. You are basically talking about two *different* types here. They happen to store the same data, albeit in different results.

To minimize errors in their usage, you should define them as two completely distinct types that have a well-defined conversion between them.

Consider for example:

```
struct old_time {
    unsigned int timeInteger;   
    unsigned int timeFraction;
};

struct new_time {
public:
    new_time(unsigned int ti, unsigned int tf) :
        timeInteger(ti), timeFraction(tf) { }

    new_time(new_time const& other) :
        timeInteger(other.timeInteger),
        timeFraction(other.timeFraction) { }

    new_time(old_time const& other) : 
        timeInteger(other.timeInteger + 2209032000U),
        timeFraction(other.timeFraction * conversion_factor) { }

    operator old_time() const {
        old_time other;
        other.timeInteger = timeInteger - 2209032000U;
        other.timeFraction = timeFraction / conversion_factor;
        return other;
    }

private:
    unsigned int timeInteger;   
    unsigned int timeFraction;
};
```

(EDIT: of course this code doesn’t work for the reasons pointed out below.

Now this code can be used frictionless in a safe way:

```
time_old told; /* initialize … */

time_new tnew = told; // converts old to new format
time_old back = tnew; // … and back.
```

Comment: I think I will follow your advice and define them as distinct types, but this doesn't help the casting problem because in the above code the conversion factor create the integer overflow. But please don't delete the above code, it is very useful

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: yes, I’m sorry I couldn’t help with the original problem … at the moment I’m having trouble wrapping my head around this since the conversion factor clearly doesn’t fit into an `unsigned int`.

Comment: I think the goal is to properly handle the integer overflow which in C and C++ will result in "wrapping around." Maybe I can create a separate variable for all the zeros associated with 2^32 and break up timeFraction into `char` or `short` and write to my binary file in pieces rather than one complete `unsigned int`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that (20 ^ -6) * (2 e32) is far bigger than UINT_MAX. Maybe you meant 2 to the power of 32, or UINT_MAX, rather than 2e32.

In addition, your first line with the integer, the initial value must be less than (2^32 - 2209032000), and depending on what this is measured in, it could wrap round too. In my opinion, set the first value to be a long long (normally 64bits) and change 2e32.

If you can't change the type, then it may become necessary to store the field as it's result in a double, say, and then cast to unsigned int before use.